# g++ (MinGW) can not convert wchar_t* to unsigned short* with option -fshort-wchar

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, mingw

I am porting a C++ Project from VisalStudio to GCC/MinGw.

The original project uses the compiler flag **/Zc:wchar_t-**, which defines the type wchar_t as an unsigned short (should be 2 bytes).
Now when I compile with g++ and the option **-fshort-wchar**. According to the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html) this option should also define wchar_t as an unsigned short.

Now there is a function

```
void myfuncExample(short unsigned int*)
```

which is called with an wchar_t* variable, which should be castable to an unsigned short*.

However, when compiling I get this error:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'wchar_t*' to 'short unsigned int*' [-fpermissive]
myfuncExample(buf);
              ^~~
```

Why can it no be converted? If i remove the -fshort-wchar option, the error is the same. It seems like g++ is ignoring the option. Any advice?

Comment: A `T` and a `U` are distinct types.  Even if `sizeof(T) == sizeof(U)` is true, that still doesn't matter.  You should probably be okay if you explicitly cast the parameter using `reinterpert_cast`

Comment: The documentation says "_Override the **underlying type** for wchar_t to be short unsigned int_" (emphasize mine). They are still distinct types, just with equal representation.

Answer (score 1):

`-fshort-wchar` sets `sizeof(wchar_t)` to 2 (which is already the default on Windows, unlike 4 elsewhere).

It doesn't make `wchar_t` the same type as `unsigned short` (even though they will have the same size and signedness).

You'll need to fix the code.

Comment: What do you mean by "Fix thwe code"? I mean the code is working when compiled with Visual Studio. I don't want to change thousand lines of code...
I think with the option /Zc:wchar_t- the type wchar_t is first undefined, but I see that in some header Files from Visual Studio the type is defined with the typedef unsigned short. 
Now, why is there no option in GCC to unset wchar_t as builtin? Basically every code ever written in VS with this flag is not portable without changing the source. But this should be a common problem, but i can not find any other discusion on this topic...

Comment: @Seff2 Like it or not, the code that relies on that isn't valid C++. I don't see any GCC flags to change this.